# Exception thrown at 0x5409B211 (ucrtbased.dll) in project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x007110E8

Tags: c

I'm trying to fill the hash_name of an array of struct hashtag from a file

the struct hashtag is

```
typedef struct{
    char hash_name[300];
    long hash_freq;
    ID_liste users;
}hashtag;
```

my functin is

```
 void load_hashtag(long ID,int* taille,hashtag *local)
 {
  int i=-1;
  char filename[100];
  sprintf(filename, "data\\fn\\%d.featnames", ID);
  long a;
    FILE * g=fopen(filename,"r");
    do{
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            local = (hashtag*)realloc(local, sizeof(hashtag));
            printf("realloc %d\n", i);
        }
        i++;
        fscanf(g,"%ld",&a);  //a numbre i don't want
        fseek(g, 2, SEEK_CUR); //tow characters i don' want
        fscanf(g, "%s", local[i].hash_name);
    }while(!feof(g));
   fclose(g);
  *taille = i;
}
```

the main is

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    hashtag* local = (hashtag*)malloc(sizeof(hashtag));
    int local_taille;
    long ID_user;
    FILE* user;
    user = fopen("User.txt", "r");
    if (user == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fscanf(user, "%ld", &ID_user);
    load_hashtag(ID_user,&local_taille,local);
    fclose(user);
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

after 50 fscanf from 1300 the program stops and the exception thrown window appear

please help

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: OT: This `... fn\\%d.featnames", ID);` should be `... fn\\%ld.featnames", ID);` as `ID` is a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is your problem:

```
local = (hashtag*)realloc(local, sizeof(hashtag));
```

You're reallocating `local` to the same size it was before.  You should [`realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) to a *larger* size, not the same size.

Comment: @MohamadMohyeddine - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.  Thank you!